# JavaScript can't read propriety previously used

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a simple game , snake to be more exact. Anyway , so here I am stuck with an error into the console that it cannot read `snake[0].x` propriety from the line with `snake[score].x = snake[0].x;` that has been preciously used

```
function scoreManager(){
    if(snake[0].x==food.x && snake[0].y==food.y){
        score++;
        snake[score].x = snake[0].x;
        snake[score].y = snake[0].y;
        food = {
            x:Math.floor(Math.random()*30+1)*cell,
            y:Math.floor(Math.random()*29+1)*cell
        };
    }
}
```

It reads it just fine in the if statement ( I know that because the score increases if the statement is true ) .

The exact error I get is :

```
> game_engine.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of
> undefined
>     at scoreManager (game_engine.js:86)
>     at draw (game_engine.js:110) scoreManager @ game_engine.js:86 draw @ game_engine.js:110 setInterval (async) (anonymous) @
> game_engine.js:127
```

Why does this happen ?
Oh , and also for some reason the new food coordinate is allways the same for some reason :/

This is the full code

```
const cvs = document.getElementById("gameArea");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

var playGround = new Image();
var foodSprite = new Image();
var sandSprite = new Image();
var snakeSprite = new Image();
var tailSprite = new Image();

playGround.src = './Textures/play_area.png';
foodSprite.src = './Textures/Food.png';
sandSprite.src = './Textures/sand.png';
snakeSprite.src = './Textures/snake_head.png';
tailSprite.src = './Textures/Snake_body.png';

//variables
const cell = 32;
let score = 1;
let direction;

//objects
let snake = [];
snake[0] = { x: 1 * cell, y: 1 * cell };

let food = {
    x:Math.floor(Math.random()*30+1)*cell,
    y:Math.floor(Math.random()*29+1)*cell
};

//controls

document.addEventListener('keydown',directionGo);
function directionGo(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'RIGHT'){
        direction = 'LEFT';
    } else
    if(event.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'DOWN'){
        direction = 'UP';
    } else
    if(event.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'LEFT'){
        direction = 'RIGHT';
    } else
    if(event.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'UP'){
        direction = 'DOWN';
    }
}
function directionManager(){
    if(direction=="LEFT"){
        snake[0].x-=cell;
    } else 
    if(direction=="RIGHT"){
        snake[0].x+=cell;
    } else 
    if(direction=="UP"){
        snake[0].y-=cell;
    } else 
    if(direction=="DOWN"){
        snake[0].y+=cell;
    } 
}

//in case u mess up
function gameOver (){
    for (let i = 1; i<snake.length; i++){
        if(snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(snake[0].x == 0*cell || snake[0].x == 32*cell || snake[0].y == 0*cell || snake[0].y == 31*cell){
        return true;
    }
}
function respawn (){
    if(gameOver() == true){
        snake = [];
        snake[0] = { x: 1 * cell, y: 1 * cell };
        score = 0;
        direction='RIGHT';
    }
}

//in case u a gud boy
function scoreManager(){
    if(snake[0].x==food.x && snake[0].y==food.y){
        score++;
        snake[score].x = snake[0].x;
        snake[score].y = snake[0].y;
        food = {
            x:Math.floor(Math.random()*30+1)*cell,
            y:Math.floor(Math.random()*29+1)*cell
        };
    }
}

function tail(){
}

//Drawing function that manages the food , map and the player
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(playGround, 0, 0); // ground

    //drawing snake
    ctx.drawImage(snakeSprite, snake[0].x, snake[0].y);
    for(let i = 1; i < snake.length; i++){
        ctx.drawImage(snakeSprite, snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
    }

    //direction o.o
    directionManager();
    scoreManager();

    //food
    ctx.drawImage(foodSprite,food.x,food.y);

    //score
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.font = '40px Changa One';
    ctx.fillText(score,16*cell+5,1*cell+15);

    //loops the animation
    //window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    respawn();
}

//draw();
let game = setInterval (draw,100);
```

Comment: if `score` is property name use `snake['score']`. You need put `''` around property name

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the offending line and check the "LOCALS" (may vary by browser) section of the debugger to see the status of your variables. I expect something (i.e. `snake` or `score`) to be uninitialized.

Comment: you are not assigning the variable back to the array

Comment: George , score is just a variable.

Comment: can you add `snake` data ?

Comment: `I am stuck with an error into the console that it cannot read snake[0].x propriety` - can you post the **exact** error message

Comment: I did now Jaromanda

Comment: because `snake[score]` **is** undefined ... you'll need to say `snake[score] = {x: snake[0].x, y: snake[0].y};` - the error isn't about `snake[0].x` it's about `snake[score].x`

Comment: by the way, that doesn't seem right, to make the tail of the snake the same spot as the head - I think it would trigger gameOver as soon as you hit food (but I could be wrong) - only a cursory look at your code

Comment: Yes however before the gameOver function is called Im going to update the head position to the next coordonate and that should do I think.